# Minimum of the maximum

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

Let $a, b,c,d,e,f,g$  seven  nonnegative real  numbers  with  the  sum  equal  to  1. Let  considered  the sums $ a+b+c$, $b+c+d$, $c+d+e$, $d+e+f$, $e+f+g$. What  is  the  minimum  of  the  maximum   of  those  sums  when  we  consider   all  the  possibilities?I  have  no  idea.  One  hint, please?

Answer (score 3):

Hint 1: Each of those sums is at least $a$ or $d$ or $g$

Hint 2: Replacing $b$ with $0$ and $a$ with $a+b$ will not increase the minimum of the maximum.  Similarly replacing $f$ with $0$ and $g$ with $f+g$

Hint 3: If $b=0$ then $b+c+d \le c+d+e$.  Similarly if $f=0$ then  $d+e+f \le c+d+e$

Hint 4: If $b=f=0$ then replacing $c$ with $0$ and replacing $d$ with $c+d+e$ and replacing $e$ with $0$ will not increase the minimum of the maximum

Hint 5: If three numbers add up to $1$ then the largest of them must be at least $\frac13$

Comment: So  what? I'm  confused

Comment: @Problemsolving I have added hints 2 and 3

Comment: How  to  replace  at  hint 2?

Comment: I  don't  understand   what   you  say

Comment: @Problemsolving I have added hints 4 and 5

Comment: So  the  value  is  1/3

Answer (score 1):

The language is obfuscating but:

Suppose $a=b=c=0$ then $d+e+g = 1$.  $d+e+g$ and that is the maximum of the sums.  But that's pretty high maximum.  What if we don't have three elements equal to $0$.  Then any sum of three numbers will not include a fourth possible none zero term.  So the sum of any three can not be as high as $1$.  So in that case the maximum will be less than $1$.

So what's the minimum the maximum can be.  That's what they are asking.

Let me explain WOLOG (without loss of generality).  The letters we use don't matter.  One of those numbers must be the least number of the seven.  Let's call that one $a$.  Without loss of generality we might as well assume that $a$ is the least element because ... some number must be and we can just relabel.   Likewise we can assume $b$ is the second least and so on.

So WOLOG $a \le b \le c \le d\le e\le g$. And so the maximum of the sums is $d+e+g$.  What is the *least* that $d+e+g$ can be if $a \le b \le c \le d\le e\le g$?

That is what is really being asked.

Now $1 = a+b+c+d+e+f+g \ge (a+b+c) + (a+b+c) = 2(a+b+c)$ so $a+b+c \le \frac 12$.

So $d+e+g = 1 - (a+b+c) \ge \frac 12$.  So $d+e+g$ *will* be at least $\frac 12$ so $\frac 12$ is the absolute minimum $d+e+g$ can be.

But *can* $d + e+g = \frac 12$?  Well, it can if $a+b+c= \frac 12$ but *can* $a+b+c = \frac 12$? Well it can if $a = b = c = \frac 16$.  And then $d+e+g$ can equal $\frac 12$ if $d=e=g=\frac 16$.

So the minimum of the maximum is $\frac 12$.

It'll take a bit more work to show that the *only* way $d+e +g = \frac 12$ is if all terms are equal to $\frac 16$ but we weren't asked to show that.

But here's how:

If $g > \frac 16$ and $d+e+g = \frac 12$ then $d+e < \frac 12 - \frac 16 = \frac 13$.  So $d+e < \frac 13$ and $2d = d + d \le d+e <\frac 13$ so $d < \frac 16$.

So $a\le b \le c \le d < \frac 16$ so $a + b + c < \frac 16 + \frac 16 + \frac 16 = \frac 16$.  But then $\frac 12 = d+e+g = 1-(a+b+c) > \frac 12$ which is a contradiction.

So $d+e+g =\frac 12 \iff g = \frac 16$.  $1 = a+b+c+d+e+g \ge a+b+c+d+g+g \ge a+b+c+g+g+g \ge a+b+g+g+g+g \ge a+g+g+g+g+g \ge g+g+g+g+g+g = 1$.  Thus $ a+b+c+d+e+g = a+b+c+d+g+g = a+b+c+g+g+g = a+b+g+g+g+g = a+g+g+g+g+g = g+g+g+g+g+g$ so $a=b=c=d=e=g=\frac 16\iff d+e+g =\frac 12$.

Comment: But  the  sumes  are  not circular,  why  I  can  asume  the  order?

Comment: WOLOG.  One of the terms must be the smallest; call that one HAROLD.  One of them must be second smallest. Call that one MAUDE.  Call the third smallest.  STAN. Call the fourth OLLIE.  Call the fifth LOU. And finally call the largest one BUD.  So $HAROLD\le MAUDE\le STAN\le OLLIE\le LOU\le BUD$.  Well those names are too long.  Let's rename $HAROLD$ as $a$ and $MAUDE$ as $b$ and so on.  Now we have $a\le b\le c\le d\le e\le g$.  Now it could be that original the order was completely different, but we renamed them. Because it doesn't *matter* what we call them.

Comment: What happened to $f$?

Comment: $\frac12$ looks too big, as $\frac37$ is obviously possible though even that is not the best answer

Comment: Oh.  I thought there were six numbers.  If there are seven numbers then it is $\frac 37$.  It is possible for the largest three.  It possible for that to be the max if they are all equal to $\frac 17$.

Comment: @Henry you seem to be right. Hmm, seeing as the sums aren't all available we can not wolog.  If $a=g=\frac 29$ and $b=c=d=e=\frac 19$ then the max are $a+b+c$ and $e+f+g=\frac 49< \frac 37$.  We can probably get smaller than that.

Comment: Let $a=d=g = \frac 15; b=c=e=f=\frac 1{10}$ then all three sums add to $\frac 25$.  That *might* be optimum.  Not sure how to prove it.

Comment: $\frac25$ is a move in the right direction, but $a=d=g=\frac13; b=c=e=f=0$ giving $\frac13$ is even better.  See my hints

Answer (score 0):

Hint, all of the sums are equal.

Comment: Why?I  don't  understand

Comment: Have  you a  complet description?

Comment: Because if one of each sums is bigger than others, such sum is not minimum of the maximum.

Comment: I  am  not  sure.  Why?

Comment: If there were six rather than seven variables (dropping $g$) and so four rather than five sums of three, then I think you could have $a=f=\frac12; b=c=d=e=0$ so the sums would be $\frac12,0,0,\frac12$ not all equal and since you would have $a+b+c+d+e+f=1$ you could not do better than $\frac12$

Comment: @Henry Yes, that's the case of 6 variables. My method give same solution with your solution, though.